# Given point in tooltiptext

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to add a point in value ex: 800000 become 800.000 when the pointer is near the bar chart

This is an example chart that I made:

[image]

Comment: Please add some code with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the documentation on making a tooltip in chart.js:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

you can add functions to tooltips.callbacks to calculate the title, data etc displayed in the tooltip.  Then, with JavaScript's NumberFormat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat you ought to be able to achieve the look you want.